# Material UI creatable multi-select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a multi-select component that's also creatable using Material UI, but I'm unable to figure out how to do that from the documentation. [autocomplate documentation page](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)

The following example is a multi-select component and it does add new values if I clicked Enter on the keyboard but it doesn't tell the user that he can add that new value. However, even in that case, I'm not sure how I can access the new array of selected options.

```
<Autocomplete
  multiple
  id="tags-filled"
  options={top100Films.map(option => option.title)}
  defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
  freeSolo
  renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
    value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip
        variant="outlined"
        label={option}
        {...getTagProps({ index })}
      />
    ))
  }
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="filled"
      label="freeSolo"
      placeholder="Favorites"
    />
  )}
/>
```

I found another example that suggest adding the new value using the filterOptions prop, but for some reason it doesn't work with the previous component.

```
filterOptions={(options, params) => {
  const filtered = filter(options, params);

  // Suggest the creation of a new value
  if (params.inputValue !== "") {
    filtered.push({
      inputValue: params.inputValue,
      title: `Add "${params.inputValue}"`
    });
  }

  return filtered;
}}
```

Here's a codesandbox for the example I mentioned:
[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8tnx4?file=/demo.js:534-1165)

So what I'm trying to achieve is making that multiselect component creatable by displaying an option for the user to add the new value and also access the final array of options.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Did you ever pull this off? If so would you be willing to share?

Answer (score 0):

While this may not solve your exact wants - it does allow you to capture the values and hitting enter creates the chips which follows gmail's functionality for email adds.

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 500,
    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Tags() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (x, emails) => console.log(x, emails);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-filled"
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={[]}
        defaultValue={""}
        freeSolo
        renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
          ))
        }
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Emails"
            placeholder="Add Email"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```